# Splash screen GIF in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am making an application with react native with native code of android and ios, in the application specifications a splash screen with a GiF is required, I have already inserted the required dependencies of the documentation of react native

```
dependencies {
  // If your app supports Android versions before Ice Cream Sandwich (API level 14)
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.3.0'

  // For animated GIF support
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'

  // For WebP support, including animated WebP
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:2.1.0'
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:2.0.0'

  // For WebP support, without animations
  implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:2.0.0'
}
```

GIF support works correctly within the screen / components. However, when I try to place the GIF on the splash screen it doesn't work, there is a static image of the GIF

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <bitmap
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/splash_screen2"/>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

How can I place a splash screen in gif format?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Lottie](https://airbnb.io/lottie/#/) yet. It is not Gif but very useful

Comment: No, I didn't try, I will try with Lottie. Thanks for the recommendation

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to convert Gif to Lottie file?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, react native only allows static images for the splash page. However a workaround that I found successful is to have a static splash screen transition into a screen containing the gif/animation which then transitions to your home screen after a timeout. You can set the splash to be identical to whatever the starting frame of your gif/animation is for continuity.

Here is a tutorial outlining how this can be achieved:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MY6rE5plNIc